# How to fix warning "Failed prop type: "value" must be a number or a range object"?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to add input-range to the page and I am getting the invalid prop type error. I can't get it - how should I fix it.
So I would be much appreciated if someone help me to finish implementing input-range component.
**Here's an error :**
[image]

**and the code (only part of the component, the whole is [here](https://gist.github.com/Y-Taras/f8844324b382e0649a82d3a3f46fab41)):**

```
.....
            <InputGroup>
              <InputRange
                maxValue={20}
                minValue={0}
                value={this.props.filterRange}
                onChange={value => this.props.handleFilterRangeChange(value)}/>
            </InputGroup>
.....
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
.....
  const filterPrice = state.filterPrice;  
.....

  return {
....
    filterRange: filterPrice
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
....
  handleFilterRangeChange(value) {
    dispatch(setFilterPrice(value));
  }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductsList);

ProductsList.defaultProps = {
.....
  filterRange: {min: 1, max: 10}
};

ProductsList.propTypes = {
....
  handleFilterRangeChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  filterVal: PropTypes.string,
  filterRange: PropTypes.shape({
    min: PropTypes.number,
    max: PropTypes.number
  })
};
```

**Here's  a reducers.js code:**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { SET_FILTER_TERM, SET_FILTER_PRICE, ADD_API_DATA } from './actions';
.....

const filterPrice = (state = {}, action) => {
  if (action.type === SET_FILTER_PRICE) {
    return action.payload;
  }
  return state;
};

.....

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ filterTerm, filterPrice, apiData });

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Can I see `handleFilterRangeChange`?

Comment: @Andrew Li  it's in the mapDispatchToProps function. or you mean someth. else?

Comment: Well, `evt.target.value` doesn't exist because you're passing the `value` object with min and max to `handleFilterTermChange`?

Comment: I guess problem is in smth. else - as far as  I understood it's in here value={this.props.filterVal}

Comment: But `onChange` for an `InputRange` passes the value object as the first argument, not an event object, so there's no `evt.target.value`.

Comment: ther must be a value according to docs in https://github.com/davidchin/react-input-range, where I took this  component from.

Comment: Oh sorry, my fault. I mixed up `handleFilterTermChange` and `handleFilterRangeChange` -- how does `setFilterPrice` work?

Comment: YEp, I also thought that smth 's wrong with reducer here's code https://gist.github.com/Y-Taras/ec4003f00bd9452e24e397df314b9f4a

Comment: Could you also post your action creators?

Comment: YEs I've updated previous link with act. creators file

Comment: Have you tried `this.props.handleFilterRangeChange(value)` instead of `({value})`?

Comment: that doesn't work, But I've find out by chance that if I rename  value={this.props.filterRange} to anything else like value={this.props.blahblah} and rename proptypes filterRange from to blahblah redux works, warnings disappear but input range doesn't change - because it doesn't get value from mapStateTo Props

Comment: @AndrewLi  Here's a changes I talking about https://gist.github.com/Y-Taras/f8844324b382e0649a82d3a3f46fab41/revisions. I've find out that redux changes it's state using redux extension tool in chrome.

Comment: It might be because the initial value for the `filterPrice` value in state is an empty object. Try doing `state = {min: 1, max: 20}`?

Comment: Pffffff exactly - it's solves a problem --- but anyway it's very confusing

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] *as text*.

Comment: @AndrewLi I added the code of reducers file, so you can add couple of lines as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check on the `value` in the `OnChange` handler of `InputRange`. Something like this:

```
    let min = 0;
    let max = 100;
    <InputRange
    {...props}
    onChange={value => {
                      const processedValues = { ...value };

                      if (processedValues.min < min) {
                        processedValues.min = min;
                      }

                     if (processedValues.max > max) {
                        processedValues.max = max;
                      }

                      this.setState({ revenue: processedValues });
                    }}
     />
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems like your value from your  component is being passed as a string. Try adding a parseInt(value) function in the beginning of the component that is receiving the value.

Also if the value IS being passed as a string put a PropTypes declaration for the value type *as a string* in the receiving component.

Maybe do something like:

`InputRange.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}`

And then in that component just proceed to immediately do `const valueNum = parseInt(value)`

Comment: value in my case is a range object - like this: {min: 1, max: 10}

Comment: Why is there an upvote on this? The `value` is not being passed as a string, and you shouldn't be parsing it as an integer!